# Hide some options from dropdown 2 when selected in dropdown 1 and vice versa

Tags: jquery

I have two select drop downs with same options. User can choose "Office address" from both select drop downs. But "Home /school address" options can select only once from either of the drop down. I referred other stack overflow answers and made some tweaks. But I couldn't able to solve below two issue. Please help me.
1. on page load - home address not disabled in second drop down
2. Office address should not be disabled since it can choose from both drop downs

JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/6qpudb52/

```
<select name="address1">
    <option value="1">Home address</option>
    <option value="2">School address</option>
    <option value="3">Office Address</option>
</select>

<select name="address2">
    <option val="">Select address</option>
    <option value="1">Home address</option>
    <option value="2">School address</option>
    <option value="3">Office Address</option>
</select>
```

Java script:

```
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='address1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='address2']");

$(document).load(function()  {
    $dropdown2.find('option').prop("disabled", false);
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem) {
        $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
$dropdown1.change(function() {
    $dropdown2.find('option').prop("disabled", false);
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem) {
        $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});

$dropdown2.change(function() {
    $dropdown1.find('option').prop("disabled", false);
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem) {
        $dropdown1.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you need [this](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/a2rujcg7/) or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/a2rujcg7/1/)?

Comment: @Satpal, I think this req doesn't full filled :- Office address should not be disabled since it can choose from both drop downs

Comment: @Satpal : thanks for quick response and help. #2 issue is not resolve in both examples (Office address should not be disabled from both drop downs when user select "office address" from either of the drop down).

Comment: @Satpal Yes and not working at all

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/a2rujcg7/2/ I haved used school adress

Comment: @Satpal : it works great!!! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hakeero/6qpudb52/4/

Note that with jQuery, it's better to use `ready` over `load` when you want to run some code after all dom elements are loaded.

Comment: And Req. 2 is not full filled in your answer too.

Comment: @mohammed-elsayed: Thank you. #2 issue - Office address should not be disabled from both drop downs when user select "office address" from either of the drop down since we should allow user to enter multiple office address.

Comment: @Nikki: got it, will update the answer within a few minutes.

Comment: glade that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the JS code to this :

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='address1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='address2']");
$dropdown1.change(function() {
  var selectedItem = $(this).val();
  if (selectedItem && selectedItem != 3) {
    $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop("disabled", true);
}
}).change();

  $dropdown2.change(function() {
  var selectedItem = $(this).val();
  if (selectedItem && selectedItem != 3) {
    $dropdown1.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop("disabled", true);
  }
  });
});
```

Added JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ox6cr2xd/

Comment: its not working as expected since if i choose "school address" option from first drop down, both "home & school" address are disabled in second drop down instead of disabling "school address" option alone. satpal shared answer helped resolving both issues.  - https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/a2rujcg7/2/. Thanks for quick response and support

Comment: oh. it was bit hard to understand what you actually wanted. just change the if condition

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='address1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='address2']");
$dropdown1.change(function() {
  var selectedItem = $(this).val();
  $dropdown2.find('option').prop("disabled", false);
  if (selectedItem && selectedItem != 3) {
    $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop("disabled", true);
  }
}).change();

$dropdown2.change(function() {
  var selectedItem = $(this).val();
  $dropdown2.find('option').prop("disabled", false);
  if (selectedItem && selectedItem != 3) {
    $dropdown1.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop("disabled", true);
  }
  });
});
```